# Relating one object to several others

Tags: ios, core-data, rubymotion

I am having an issue implementing the following use case:

A `Foo` has a to-one relationship to a `Bar`, via a relationship named `myBar`. More than one `Foo` can have the same `Bar`, however.

I am coming from a web application background, where I would give `Foo` a `bar_id`, and have the `myBar` relationship method query for all `Bar`s with that `bar_id`. I am aware that Core Data isn't an ORM, but I was hoping that something similar may be possible.

**The problem I am experiencing is that setting the same `Bar` instance to several `Foo`s causes the previous relationships to revert to `nil`.**

Do I have no choice but to implement a many-to-many relationship? I really wanted to just call the `myBar` method and have it return the `Bar` instance, not a set of what will only ever be 1 `Bar`.

I am implementing this project in RubyMotion and include an example of my problem below. Objective-C devs shouldn't have a problem following, but this question is more one of principle than specific code I have written.

```
# assume `b` is some instance of Bar

f1 = Foo.alloc.init
f1.bar = b
# calling f1.bar getter now returns the `b` instance of Bar

f2 = Foo.alloc.init
f2.bar = b

# f2.bar getter returns the Bar instance, but *f1.bar does not* - it is now nil.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem:

The `Foo` → `Bar` relationship was correctly set as to-one, but, the inverse (`Bar` → `Foo`) wasn't set as to-many.